# Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows, Lifecycle Events not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-store

I'm going through the JavaScript Windows Store app tutorials. After implementing the restore after suspend & terminate code I tried to use the Lifecycle Events "Suspend and shutdown" toolbar button to test it.

However I get an immediate error from VS: "The application cannot be suspended and shut down. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0xffffffff." And no effect on the app in the debugger at all.

Is this working for anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

On the general toolbar in Visual Studio, change the dropdown from Local Machine to Simulator, then Debug > Start Debugging.

Now you can use the Lifecycle Events dropdown on the Debug Location toolbar to choose Suspend, Resume, and Suspend and shutdown.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thank you for taking the time to provide a useful answer as well!  Feel free to look at the site tour on help --> site tour to get a free badge!